# How to replace the content of a column by a specific string?

Tags: replace, pyspark

*Hi Everyone*

*So , I have This table (which is just a subset of the original dataset) :*

```
   Customer                        Country
IT - Rome - Bank Of America        Italy
DE - Berlin - BNP ParisBas         Germany
IT - Rome - BNP ParisBas           Italy
FR - Paris - CreditAgricole        France
```

*And what i want is to replace every string that starts with ***IT - Rome*** with the string ***IT - Rome - societe generale****

*So , my output should look like this:*

```
   Customer                        Country
IT - Rome - societe generale       Italy
DE - Berlin - BNP ParisBas         Germany
IT - Rome - societe generale       Italy
FR - Paris - CreditAgricole        France
```

*Any help on how to achieve that would be greatly appreciated , thank you*

Comment: Did you want to do this in Python specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `like` operator in Pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.withColumn("Customer", F.when(col('Customer').like('IT - Rome%')\
    , 'IT - Rome - societe generale').otherwise(col('Customer'))).show()

+----------------------------+-------+
|Customer                    |Country|
+----------------------------+-------+
|IT - Rome - societe generale|Italy  |
|DE - Berlin - BNP ParisBas  |Germany|
|IT - Rome - societe generale|Italy  |
|FR - Paris - CreditAgricole |France |
+----------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not what you are asking..
Are you looking for this simple update statement?
Assuming your table name is Table_1

```
UPDATE Table_1
   SET Customer = 'IT-Rome - societe generale'
 WHERE Customer like ('IT - ROME%')
GO
```

Comment: I want to replace all the strings in the Customer column that start with IT - ROME with IT - Rome - societe generale .